# Where are the standard operator functions defined?

Tags: c++, operators

As far as I understood

```
if (n>1)
```

stands for

```
if (greater(n,1))
```

Where is the function for `>` defined?

Answer (score 1):

It is not "defined" anywhere. It is an integral part of the compiler and the language. `int`, `float`, etc. are *standard types*, so there is no source file describing them or something but they are implemented in the compiler.
In the case described above, `>` directly compiles down to instruction/s in the native instruction set.

The upper case is only for `n` being of one of these standard types. If `n` is an object of a user-defined type like `std::complex`, the class is free to implement the operator (in shape of the `std::complex::operator>` member function) just as you mentioned; only there is no `greater` function but it's called as uttered before. By default, this member function is unimplemented, though, so applying it to arbitrary user-defined objects will not work for sure.

Answer (score 1):

`n>1` doesn't stand for `greater(n,1)`. It *can* stand for `operator>(n,1)` or `n.operator>(1)` under certain circumstances.

The basic rules are that if no operand of an operator in an expression has a class or enumeration type, the operator is assumed to be built-in. Built-in operators are not functions, their meaning is defined directly in the standard (specifically, Clause 5).

If one of the operands *is* of class or enumeration type, a user-defined operator function might be declared which implements the operator. Alternatively, some user-defined conversions could be used to convert to appropriate types for using built-in operators.

So `operator>(n,1)` is not defined somewhere assuming `n` is of a type which is compatible with the built-in operators when used with in `int`. Otherwise, `operator>(decltype(n), int)` could be declared as a free function somewhere, or `operator>(int)` could be declared in the definition of `n`'s type, or there could be some user-defined conversion from `decltype(n)` so that the built-in operator can be used.

Comment: thank you friends. Is this a correct syntax: 1.operator<(n) or int(1).operator<(n)?

Comment: @Holonout no, because `int` doesn't have any member functions. It's a fundamental type.